# How to keep an aggregate from one table in another

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables:

1. Post(post_id Text, ...)
2. Like(post_id Text, client_id Text)

The number of likes for a post is used to calculate the score of the post. In most of my queries posts are ordered based on the score. I would like to keep the total of likes for each post as a generated column in my Post table in order to not calculate it on every post. Does anybody know how to do this in postgresql?

Comment: Write a trigger.  The smarter idea is not to keep that count in your `post` table and calculate it when you query.

Comment: @MikeOrganek Yes, a trigger. But "*In most of my queries posts are ordered based on the score. I would like to not calculate it on every post [in each query]*" is pretty clear, and is a reasonable and smart idea. Keeping the count in the `post` table allows indexing.